# How to filter custom posts by term name

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

How to filter custom post type posts by term name?
I got the post loop almost working, only i want to change the amount of items per page instead the amount of terms per page and offcourse the pagination need to adjust to the amount of pages that i set.

If you have a shorter way that is also fine, iam looking for the best and easy way to do this.

```
// Get all the categories
$categories = get_terms( 'document-type' );
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$post_type = 'documentation';
$taxonomy  = 'document-type';

// count the number of terms for correct pagination
$term_count = get_terms( array (
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'fields'   => 'count',
) );

// define the number of terms per page
$terms_per_page = 2;

// find out the number of pages to use in pagination
$max_num_pages = ceil( $term_count / $terms_per_page );

// get the page number from URL query
$current_page = get_query_var( 'paged', 1 );

// calculate offset
$offset = ( $terms_per_page * $current_page ) - $terms_per_page;

// get all taxonomy terms
$terms = get_terms( array (
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'order'    => 'ASC',
    'orderby'  => 'name',
    'number'   => $terms_per_page,
    'offset'   => $offset,
) );

// cycle through taxonomy terms
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

    // cycle through posts having this term
    $items = get_posts( array (
        'post_type'   => $post_type,
        'tax_query'   => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'terms'    => $term->term_id,
            ),
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // different from WP_Query (see Code Ref)
    ) );

    // essential, see comments inside foreach() loop
    global $post;

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
     the_title();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata(); // moved outside the foreach() loop


}
```

That some can help me to find a nice way to order custom post type by term name with pagination